# Is there a place where I can see colors outside of RGB space?

Tags: color-reproduction

Given the fact that the RGB color space does not include all colors (perceptible by human eye), is there a place where I can see all colors? Like, a museum of materials that reflect a color beyond RGB? Maybe monitors that uses additive colors other than RGB (or extends RGB)?

Please don't say anything like "go outside, the nature provides".

Comment: You can make  or buy a custom super bright RGB source. It surely can generate colors beyond the standard sRGB range, but I guess this is not worth to be written as an answer. Color reference cards like Pantone, RAL and Munsell can show a bunch of colors which are not possible in ordinary RGB monitors. One must watch the cards in bright enough white light. But they are discrete colors, not all possible non-rgb colors. Some LSD addicts have claimed they can see colors which are beyond everything that they have seen before, but I wouldn't trust them nor try the same nor recommend to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one place where you can go and see all the colors that your monitor can not show. Mainly because there's infinite variability.

The classical method is to order a color reference from a color manufacturer, you can get Pantone color cards, RAL color cards, you can get a sample set from acrylic manufacturers and so on. Alternatively you can get a  high quality Mussel color chart which is probably the closest thing you to what you ask.

[image]

**Image 1**: Acrylic color samples that I have laying aroud. *NOTE*: Image is not representative of how bright they are since neither the camera nor your monitor can understand the brilliance. (essentially the darkest colors are just black in image and most saturated colors are dulled. But also because of artificial lighting does not give enough wavelengths)

Then there are colors that are even beyond any of the charts, just burn some table salt with Bunsen burners and you get a very unique color.* While all of this sounds nice, its not really all that spectacular since our vision is relative.

If you just want to see a single color that monitor can not make take a look at any of the attention colors construction workers use. You also get a lot of dark colors that monitors can not make with printing. Most rich blacks are like that.

* If by all you truly means all then it is also probable that you can not see all the colors. Some humans have alternate color receptors some even have 4 color receptors! And most humans could in very specific lightning conditions also have the night vision on at the same time as color vision leading to interesting color combinations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll have to look into getting those color cards. I am curious though, wouldn't printed cards have the similar limitations as RGB would? It's my understanding most printers use CMYK color space, and inks have the limitation with the brightness (much more so than standard monitors).

Comment: @Harplife Well no, they are printed with individual inks not cmyk process. That is also why they are expensive as you need to have quite many passes to print the books (dont get a cmyk guide). But those inks are after all what they sell. But yes CMYK can do colors that your monitor can not, but also the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Just some clarifications. Some terminology is important.

**RGB is not a space. It is a color mode** that gives instructions to a device that uses the same 3 base colors. Red, green and blue.

**The amount of colors that the device can represent is defined by a color space.**

Imagine a bad monitor that only has some dim led lights behind it. That can only represent some colors. It has physical limitations on how many colors can display.

On the other hand, you have a "pro monitor", that can, not only display really bright colors, but the difference between them is very smooth.

That difference in how the colors can be displayed is what is known as **color space**.

Some common color spaces are sRGB for consumer-grade monitors, Rec. 709 or DCI-P3 for video, television, and movies, and AdobeRGB. And all of them can work in RGB color mode.

---

So, your first stop could be **using a better monitor** that can reproduce a bigger color space than sRGB.

---

The second stop could be **using a physical catalog for spot inks**. Additive colors is not enough, because the color space for a CMYK-based reproduction is also limited, more or less as an Adobe color space. That is why they are used together.

A spot ink is a series of chemicals that reflect wavelengths in a different way than CMYK. Some colors will be inside a CMYK space, but some others will be beyond it.

Some of those inks, like fluorescent inks, even convert some UV light into visible wavelengths.

But a specific limitation of the concept of "ink" and "paint" is that the color is meant to be seen by **reflection**.

---

A third stop could be **other materials not printed**, but you are limiting this stop "go outside, the nature provides". You can not do that.

Chemistry is limited. Limited by a combination of cost, efficiency, safety, etc. You could probably have a cyan brighter but very costly to produce, or toxic. Yes, some other materials can have very vivid colors, sometimes by the chemicals inside it or by the way they are lighted.

An acrylic material could look brighter because you can see not only light reflected on it but also light refracted or diffused inside it.

That phenomenon is more common in nature. Tree leaves have a lot of tones because the light that passes thru them, not only reflects light but scatters it.

**So the next stop is to go outside, the nature provides**.

This nature **includes sunlight**. An RGB divide is a way to provide a cost-effective way to combine a limited set of wavelengths to simulate some other fooling our brains. I remember there was an RGB+Y(fellow) color monitor. But sunlight has a nice combination of wavelengths our eyes evolved to perceive.

---

An additional idea is that color is relative.

Take a good quality monitor, let's say your cellphone. In a room, you could see a bright picture of some bushes. You might see some nice shadows and gradients.

Take your phone into the sunlight and the range of colors you will see on the phone will be almost black colors because you are now comparing them to other light conditions.

So, do not expect to see some "new colors" here and there, even in another planet. You will see the same, under different conditions and you will probably not notice the difference. Sometimes you notice a difference only by direct comparation.